# Where are FTP credentials stored?

Tags: windows, windows-10, credentials-manager

I like to use Windows File Explorer as a quick ftp client as it can be convenient.

I have a long-time site where the credentials have been remembered by Files Explorer. I now need to find out what the password is. I am unable to find it in `Credential Manager`. Where are the credentials stored on my PC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The passwords for each FTP connection made through File Explorer are stored in the registry under:
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\FTP

It is encrypted though. The password is not stored in plain text.

If you really need to figure this out you will have to use WireShark (or similar) to capture the network traffic while you make the FTP connection.
FTP is insecure as hell because it sends the password in plaint-text over the connection. So WireShark (or another capture tool) can simply lift the info from the network traffic.